# Set linear velocity of a moving box2d object ( own velocity + player velocity )

Tags: c++, sdl, box2d

I'm just trying to program a game with Box2D/ SDL2 & C++. Unfortunately, I am not really getting on with a problem. In the game there are boxes (b2_dynamicBody) that are generated at the click of a mouse. These then fall down. The character is in the middle and when it is moved I create speed X and Y with

`m_pCamera->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(z.B. x = 0.0f, y = 10.0f));`

I then add within the game loop to any speed of my own box the speed of the character.

`ObjectIterator>SetLinearVelocity(ObjectIterator->GetLinearVelocity() + m_pCamera->GetLinearVelocity());`

<del>Unfortunately, there are always funny results and I don't know exactly where I need to look.</del>

> When I move the player the falling boxes velocity is slowing down!

Here is a source code excerpt :

```
for (boxit = m_pBoxList.begin(); boxit != m_pBoxList.end(); boxit++) {

            if ((*boxit)->getBody()->GetType() == b2_kinematicBody) {
                (*boxit)->getBody()->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0,0));
            }

            if((*boxit)->getBody()->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody && m_pCamera->getBody()->GetLinearVelocity().x != 0.0f) {
                (*boxit)->getBody()->SetLinearVelocity(m_pCamera->getBody()->GetLinearVelocity());
            }
            else {
                (*boxit)->getBody()->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2((*boxit)->getBody()->GetLinearVelocity().x + m_pCamera->getBody()->GetLinearVelocity().x, (*boxit)->getBody()->GetLinearVelocity().y + m_pCamera->getBody()->GetLinearVelocity().y));
            }

            (*boxit)->Update();
            (*boxit)->Render();
            (*boxit)->RenderOutline();
        
            if ((*boxit)->getBody()->GetLinearVelocity().y == 0.0f) {
                (*boxit)->getBody()->SetType(b2_kinematicBody);
            }
        }
```

Screenshot:
[screenshot / error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8THO.png)

Comment: _Unfortunately, there are always funny results_ is not yet what I would consider as a precise error description...

Comment: What is the point of the game? What does the character do with the boxes?